# Integrating Smarty into Zend Framework 1.10

Tags: php, zend-framework, smarty

I searched through Google and there was little to no information about how to integrate Smarty 2.x into Zend Framework 1.10.

Can anyone help me figure out how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This a little older, but should provide you with a good starting point. http://anders.tyckr.com/2008/03/12/implementing-zend-layout-and-smarty-using-zend-framework-mvc/

Comment: Kind of complicated :P Nevertheless, thanks for your help, that should get me started.

Answer (score 1):

But also consider this.

It is absolutely senseless to integrate Smarty with ZF unless you also integrate some script that aready use smarty. But i would not use smarty with ZF in any case like

1. I know how to work with smarty and I do not want to learn new I just want to continue use smarty
2. I think smarty is powerful
3. I do not know how to do it without smarty
4. I think smarty wil make my project more advanced

Smarty is advanced, powerful and great templating system but ZF has it's own MVC and I would not messup with it.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a simpler implementation

http://www.mooduino.co.uk/2010/07/using-php-smarty-template-engine-with.html

Answer (score -1):

http://devzone.zend.com/article/120

Please have a look it seems like best solution to integrate

Comment: Please don't post a link as an answer with no content summary. It is likely to be deleted if the link breaks